# Tomcat deploy from public_html war application

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

Hello I'm trying to deploy .war application from the public_html  folder at user homes.

I've added  directive to server.xml  :

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.UserConfig" 
          directoryName="public_html" 
          userClass="org.apache.catalina.startup.PasswdUserDatabase"/>`
```

And I try :

`http://localhost:8080/~usertest/app`

And it return :  `404 error`

Then I try : `http://localhost:8080/~usertest/app.war`

It download app.war but it doesn't serve the app.

User home contains folder :

```
public_html/app.war
```

So, what is the problem?
I'm using tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, and ask on tomcat mail-list, It's not possible to deploy (and execute) WAR files inside public_html user's homes.
Tomcat haven't this feature, but there is one alternative:

Create one virtual host per user (hostname, or port), where each user deploy war applications, like (server.xml) :

```
...
<Connector port="8082" ....
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="app_user_a" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
...
<Connector port="8083" ....
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="app_user_b" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
...
```